# Java Ceaser Cipher program not working properly

Tags: java, debugging

My program is supposed to print out a string, but instead, it prints out 100, for each lowercase letter, and 68 for each upper case letter, in the user input message.

Anything positive and constructive that can be said about the code to help my program work, or to make my program better would be highly appreciated.

I think my error is either in my main, or calcOffset.

Thanks.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

class CeaserCipher{

    char[] Alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String in;
        int off;


        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Message: ");
        in = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Offset: ");
        off = sc.nextInt();

        String out = new CeaserCipher().ceaser(in, off);

        System.out.println(out);

    }

    public String ceaser(String in, int off){

        char[] useMe = in.toCharArray();

        String output = " ";

        for(int j=0; j!=useMe.length; j++){
            if(Character.isUpperCase(useMe[j]))
                output += Character.toUpperCase(calcOffset(getIndex(useMe[j]), off));
            else
                output += calcOffset(getIndex(useMe[j]), off);
        }
        return output;
    }
    public int getIndex(char letter){

        if (Character.isUpperCase(letter)){
            letter = Character.toLowerCase(letter);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i != Alphabet.length; i++){
                return i;
            }
            return 999;
        }

    public int calcOffset(int index, int off){

        if((index + off) < 0){
            int newIndex = 26 + (index+off);

            return Alphabet[newIndex];
        }
        if((index + off) > 25){
            int newIndex = (index+off) - 26;

            return Alphabet[newIndex];
        }
        if((index + off) >= 0 && (index + off) < 25){
            int newIndex = (index + off);

            return Alphabet[newIndex];
     }

     return 'X';
    }

  }
```

Comment: did you try to debug it? what did you find out? Does calcOffset behave as expected if run isolated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code in getIndex method is causing your problem -

```
for (int i = 0; i < Alphabet.length; i++){
            return i;
        }
```

To me it seems you are always returning 0 and thus your calcOffset is also returning same value. Correcting it you should get correct result.
Hope that helps.